# Is this hole in the sink drain a defect and causing a leak?

Tags: leak, sink

Update: comment answered my question. The hole is normal.

I tried to replace and the sink trap because there was a leak after my super installed a new one and over tightened the nuts which may have caused those visible sink cracks.

I got new parts and put everything together but I still find a light leak coming from the top nuts so I took it back apart and noticed there is a hole in the sink drain itself.

Notice a little bit of cracks and a hole through the drain on the right side. Does this mean the sink is defective and I need to replace it to completely stop the leaks?

[image]

Comment: Is that a metal sink ?

Comment: " there was a leak after my super installed a new one" implies apartment building which implies the "super" (presumably maintenance or building supervisor) needs to correct it until it's fixed, not that it's your problem to fix.

Comment: You can call it maintenance but it's just one person who normally makes things worse than it already is. He overnighten the nut against my instructions causing the cracks in the sink. Anyway, I fixed it my self by replacing the defective washers and installing them correctly. One of the gaskets was installed upside down

Comment: @isherwood your comment is the answer to my question. If you add it, I'll accept it and the answer ..thx

Comment: Your question has several aspects, and this particular one about the overflow drain hole doesn't address the actual problem. I'd rather we solve that.

Comment: Yes, you were right about 1. Cracks are on the surface, 2 hole is normal so the sink is not defective based on what I provided. Thx

Comment: Repair the surface with Tub, Tile and Shower, Fiberglass and Porcelain Repair Kit for Sink Shower & Cracked Bathtub Scratches - Bathtub Refinishing Kit (White) found on Amazon

Comment: If you try a home repair kit and your landlord notices, you might be buying a them new sink (and an expensive plumber for install).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That hole is the overflow port return. It's cast into the body of the sink and leads down from the inlet up high.